# ng-select can't reset to a default value in ionic popover

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ng-select that is working as expected, minus the fact that when I execute a function to update its ng-model, it updates various other filters and things that rely on the value, but it doesn't actually reset the html option.

When you select an ion tab, it runs the function resetFilters(), as in this snippet of html:

```
...
<ion-tab on-select="resetFilters('required')" title="Required" icon-on="ion-university" icon-off="ion-university">
...
```

When you select the value "Descending" in the dropdown, then click on a tab, it runs the resetFilters() function just fine, but it doesn't reset it back to "Ascending", it's just stuck on "Descending".

Here is the html for the ng-select:

```
<ion-popover-view>
  <ion-content>
    <ul class="list search-filter-list">
      <li class="item">
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
          <div class="input-label">
            Sort
          </div>
          <select id="sort-direction" ng-model="sortDirectionItem"
                  ng-options="sort as sort.direction for sort in filterTitleItems.sort"
                  ng-change="filterByTitleDirection(sortDirectionItem)">
          </select>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  <ion-content>
<ion-popover-view>
```

And here is the javascript that affects this:

```
$scope.resetFilters = function(tab) {
      $scope.selectedTab = tab;
      $scope.nameFilter = 'name';
      $scope.enrollmentFilterStatus = 'all';
      $scope.completionFilterStatus = 'all';
      $scope.sortDirectionItem = $scope.filterTitleItems.sort[0];
    }


    /* =================================
       Filter: By title - ascending/descending
       ================================= */
    $scope.filterTitleItems = {sort: [
        {
          direction: "Ascending",
        },
        {
          direction: "Descending",
        }
      ]
    }

    // Initialize the filter
    $scope.nameFilter = 'name';
    $scope.sortDirectionItem = $scope.filterTitleItems.sort[0];

    $scope.filterByTitleDirection = function(item) {

      if(item.direction == 'Ascending') {
        $scope.nameFilter = 'name';
      } else {
        $scope.nameFilter = '-name';
      }
    }
```

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Your code miss some important info to understand and to replicate your issue: for example the select component is in a PopOver; when is it opened? Besides check your code sintax: ionic tags aren't properly closed! (eg <ion-content>...<ion-content>)

Comment: You could adapt a CodePen like this http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz in order to clarify the issue and help other users to support you

Comment: @beaver Thanks for the comment, I believe that was a typo. The PopOver is opened via a button like this: <button class="button button-icon filter icon ion-funnel" ng-click="openPopover($event)"></button>